# Next 13 app routing giving 404 in playwright only

Tags: postgresql, docker, firefox, next.js, playwright

I have been teaching myself Next JS 13, and I'm trying to hit as many areas as I can. So I've added Playwright tests to the project, and it has a PostGres database, which runs in a container during tests.

The problem I'm having is that when I go to a specific route that pops up a modal for editing, I get a 404 in Playwright only. If I add a custom error.tsx file to the app root, I don't get a 404 and the error component does not appear. In Chrome and Edge, all my tests pass with the custom error page in place, but in Firefox the UI does not update when navigating back from editing, so the test fails (this is actually a condensed version of what really happens--I'll add details if they seem relevant). I figure the failures in Firefox indicate that there's a real underlying error that I just mask by creating a custom error page, but I am at a loss to figure out what it is. I also don't especially want a custom error page.

I'm not sure if the error is Next related or Playwright related.

The project is here:
https://github.com/AmyBlankenship/next-contacts-example/tree/feat/add-address

Since the tests run against a containerized database, anyone who wants to look at this should be able to get it running without needing to have my tables in their postgres, or postgres at all.

You should be able to get going with:

```
yarn install
npm run test:e2e
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

*Update: If I add slowMo to the Playwright config file to slow it down, all the tests pass. I'd really rather not do that.*

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for [this bug](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/52850) is to set slowMo to 2000 in playwright.